# How to select all js files which is located in a folder or under a subfolder

Tags: php, html

I want to import my script files dynamicly. I've coded a simple think but it is not working how I expected. I want to select all js files which is located in a folder and its subfolders.

```
    <script src="front/js/assets/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <?php
        foreach (glob( 'front/js/**/*.js') as $jsFile):
            $exception = [
                'front/js/assets/jquery-3.6.0.min.js',
                'front/js/main.js'
            ];
            if(!in_array($jsFile, $exception))
            echo '<script src="'.$jsFile.'"></script>'. PHP_EOL. "\t";
        endforeach;
    ?>
    <script src="front/js/main.js"></script>
```

In this code, example.js is not loaded.

[my folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWNDQ.png)

Comment: Ok. And what debugging have you done?

Comment: I've checked it from source codes on browser.

Comment: thats the question already. What should I use instead of `**` ?

Comment: Does it find the bootstrap and swiper files? Does it find main.js (if you remove it from the exclusion list and remove the manual addition)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust your pattern this way. Note that the **GLOB_BRACE** flag allows you to replace {a, b, c} with 'a', 'b' or 'c'

```php
glob('{front/js/*.js,front/js/**/*.js}', GLOB_BRACE)
```

**NB**: Also The GLOB_BRACE flag is not available on some non-GNU systems, such as Solaris.

For more information, you can follow this link [glob — Find pathnames matching a pattern](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)